# Find the possible shortest path between two vertices

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, computer-science

So let's say I have a graph like this, I can only visit 6 vertices at a time, for example, I can visit maybe 123654 for the first time and when I move again I need to start at the end vertex I visited last time so for the example given I have to start at 4, then I can do 432567. The goal is to start from 1 and end at exactly 7 for my last element of any moves.

Is there any way to achieve this? I have been stuck on this problem for weeks now, so far my idea is to keep exploring all the possible routes I may find but I don't think it is a correct algorithm, is there a better idea?
[image]

Comment: A screenshot ... of Paint? Why? :)

Comment: Do you always need to visit exactly 6 vertices? Or up to 6?

Comment: always 6 and screenshot just give you an example lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1.** Find all the paths of the length 6 from vertex 1 (V1). You can use DFS for that:

123456
123654
125436
125634

I assume, that you can't visit the same vertex twice in the same "run". If you can you'll get a bigger list.

**Step 2.** Find all the paths of the length 6 from V7:

765432
765234
763452
763254

**Step 3.** Find a vertex you can reach in a single run from both V1 and V7

It's vertex number 4. Then you can construct two runs that let you go from V1 to V7:

123654
432567

**Step 4.** You can generalize this algorithm to an arbitrary graph.

1. Using DFS or BFS build a list of vertices reachable from V1.
2. Repeat this step for every vertex reachable from V1 until you reach V7 (or V[Last]).

What you need is to run a short DFS (6-vertex "runs") within a long DFS (vertices reachable after each run).

Comment: could you please explain why is it number 4?

Comment: @newToJava All the paths from 1 end in 4 and 6. The paths from 7 end in 2 and 4. Number 4 is a common element, reachable from both ends.

Comment: so if there is no common element from start vertex and end vertex it will just keep recursively running the method till there is a common element?

Comment: @newToJava Yes, this is the one way to do it. But you don't really have to move from both ends. You can just run the method recursively from every vertex reachable from the start (from V1 then from V2, then from V4) until you reach the end. I did it from both ends just to make the explanation a bit shorter.